# Fixing the URL independent of the directory

Tags: html, url

I have a URL `www.foo.com` with a directory structure given by

```
bar/
    /baz.html
```

When I display the `baz.html` page the URL displays `www.foo.com/public/bar/baz.html`. Is there any way to make the URL **only** display `foo.com` independent of the page being shown?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of web server are you using? Apache/nginx etc.?

Comment: @Laurens Thanks for your comment. Does this have to be implemented on the server, rather than in the HTML file?

Comment: Yes, this is something that your webserver handles. When you are using Apache for example you can change these settings in the .htaccess file